# Python Using While Loop And For Loop

Tags: python

How to wriite a program that input three numbers from user. All numbers Must be positive, if user 
enters a negative number, your program should keep asking user to enter a positive number
until user enters a positive number?

Comment: We don't do homework for people.  You need to try writing this yourself, and ask questions.

Comment: Hi Rana, just to echo what Ned has said. This seems like a homework question. Please let us know what kind of things you have tried before asking for help on StackOverflow.

Comment: You can use a while loop for this purpose.As others have said, writing the answer would be like doing your homework, but use while and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Because others have said not to do others' homework, I will instead make my answer this:

Use a `while` loop to make sure the input is negative.
Use a `for` loop to repeat this three times.